# How to share 1 monitor with 2 PCs

Tags: switch, kvm-switch

I have 1 monitor and 2 PCs. I would like to connect either PC via DVI cable with a single monitor. 
Does exists some DVI cable with 2 IN connector and 1 Output (monitor) with the possibility to switch it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The KVM tag says it all.  You should be looking for something like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817399063).  Your keyboard, mouse and monitor plug into the KVM, and then the KVM plugs into your two computers.

Comment: I know, but i would like to know if exists some specific cable.. not kvm!

Comment: Every KVM I've ever used uses standard cables for the mouse, keyboard and monitor (be they PS/2 or USB, VGA or DVI), and either cables that can't be detached from the KVM or a set of special cables supplied with the KVM for connecting to the computers.  If you're looking for a cable that just goes from your monitor to 2 computers, I'm sorry, but they don't exist.